# How to start parsing ARXML file from a specific node?

Tags: python, xml, loops

I am writing a Python script that takes information from another file and inserts this information in the form of a comment into the ARXML file in a specific location. The script is currently using a plain for loop to iterate through the ARXML file until it finds the desired tag.

However, repeatedly parsing the ARXML file from the beginning each time I am inserting is incredibly time consuming. I am trying to optimize this part by creating a for loop that simply begins parsing at the desired LXML node (a specific tag that I am looking for).

I am using LXML instead of XML's ElementTree library because LXML library has a convenient function called addprevious().

I have searched for this question and read posts related to ARXML parsing but it does not answer this specific question.

Since I actually know in advance what tags I am looking for, my question is how would I begin parsing the ARXML file from this desired node using LXML's iter() or iterparse()? Is there a way to set the beginning search node in LXML's iter()?

Current code:

```
# begins parsing from the very beginning of the file
for elem in lxml_root.iter():
    # logic here that first locates the desired node... everytime
```

Desired code (at high level):

```
# already found the desired node
elem = desired_lxml_node 
for elem in lxml_root.iter():
    # already parsing from desired node
```

Has anyone achieved something similar to this in LXML?

Answer (score 0):

Lxml supports XPath, so you could use that to quickly find your node:

desired_lxml_node tree.xpath('/AR-PACKAGE/APPLICATION-SW-COMPONENT')

(note: My Xpath probably is not correct, and you also have additional constraints that you can add, such as [@shortName == 'whatever']